# HTML text field input can only accept 1 or 0 as a value in Perl

Tags: html, perl, module, gentoo

may i ask, how can HTML accept a text field input with only 1 or 0 as its value?
Can anybody show me? I implement this HTML in my perl.

Here is the example of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#index5.cgi

require 'foobar-lib.pl';
ui_print_header(undef, $module_info{'desc'}, "", undef, 1, 1);
ui_print_footer("/", $text{'index'});
#print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
print qq~<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<body>

<div id="content">
<div id="bar">
<span><p>Data Gateaway</p></span>
</div>
<div id="main-container">
<table border="0" width="100%" height="100%">
<tr>
<td colspan="5">
<div id="button">
<form action="index.cgi">
<input type="submit" value="Back">
</form>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="25%" align="left">
<div id="title"><span>BYPASS :</span></div>
</td>
<td width="20%">
<form method="POST" action="index7.cgi">
<td width="20%">
<table border="0" style=\"text-align:top;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\" cellpadding="5">
<tr>
<td width="20%"><div id="data">Use either "1" or "0" to change value for <b>Basics Bypass</b>:</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<td align="left" width="7%">
<table border="0" style=\"text-align:center;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;\" cellpadding="2">
<td>
<tr>
<td width="7%">
<input type="text" maxlength="1" name="voca" size="1">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="7%">
<input type="text" maxlength="1" name="vocb" size="1">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="7%">
<input type="text" maxlength="1" name="vocc" size="1">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="7%">
<input type="text" maxlength="1" name="vocd" size="1">
</td>
</tr>
</td>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5">
<div id="description"><b>Description :</b></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="5">
<div id="button">
<input type="submit" value="Change Default Settings"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
~;
```

What function do i must add for that the text field input in the HTML only can accept the value of 1 or 0 only? Can anybody teach me how? Do i need to use if..else statement?

Comment: It's 2014 and you're still writing CGI programs that include raw HTML in your Perl code. It's over fifteen years since we worked out what a terrible idea that was.

Comment: I just wanna learn. It's not wrong to learn even it is a long time ago is it? I just want to try and learn. @Dave Cross

Comment: Learning is never wrong, of course. But why not learn [something contemporary](http://plackperl.org/)?

Comment: I will do my best @DaveCross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I think its better to use dropbox with options of 1 and 0 in order to make it more intuitive. If you really want to use textbox, make input type=number, and every time that onchange event is being called, validate the current value and delete it if its invalid.

Comment: I can't use radio button or dropbox or anything because i have so many fields to be filled actually. So i needed to use text field so it could look more user friendly. But apart from that, i will try doing it by your suggestion. Hope it works. @Aviran

Comment: Having a dropdown won't prevent someone from hand-crafting a request that contains another value. You need to check this on the server side too.

Comment: Dave is right, as always server side validation is a must

Answer (score 0):

To make 0 and 1 the only accepted input, add a [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) attribute:

```
pattern="0|1"
```

But (in addition to lack of support in old browsers) this does not prevent the user from typing something else. It just means that upon form submission, the data is checked and and an error message is issued if the check does not pass. Moreover, an empty string will pass, too, unless you also use the attribute `required`.

To actually prevent the user from type anything but 0 or 1, you would need to use a small piece of JavaScript.

In general, checkboxes are usually preferable when there are only two values that you wish to accept.

And all such methods are just for helping the user, not for security. Your server-side code  should check the data before doing anything with it.

Comment: I will try to implement this. But i really don't want javascript involve in my coding. But i'll give it a try. Thanks dude. @jukka